# How to set S3ObjectSummary of ObjectListing class?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Reference: This is decompiled .class file and hence cannot be changed.

```
package com.amazonaws.services.s3.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ObjectListing implements Serializable {
  private List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaries = new ArrayList();
  private List<String> commonPrefixes = new ArrayList();
  private String bucketName;
  private String nextMarker;
  private boolean isTruncated;
  private String prefix;
  private String marker;
  private int maxKeys;
  private String delimiter;
  private String encodingType;

  public ObjectListing() {
  }

  public List<S3ObjectSummary> getObjectSummaries() {
    return this.objectSummaries;
  }
```

There is no setObjectSummaries method present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It can be solved by passing the value with reference:

```
S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary = new S3ObjectSummary();

    ObjectListing objects = new ObjectListing();
    objects.setBucketName(bucket);
    objects.setPrefix(prefix);

    List<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummaries = objects.getObjectSummaries();
    objectSummaries.add(s3ObjectSummary);
```